# Etique meta description author y keywors en todas las paginas html?

Tags: html, html5, web, seo

Hola buenas noches tengo una pregunta acerca de contenido web: 
las etiqueta meta por ejemplo estas:

```
<meta name="author" content="aulaclic">
<meta name="description" content="Curso de HTML gratuito">
<meta name="keywords" content="código HTML etiqueta página web gratis curso">
```

deben ir en todas las paginas .html o simplemente en el index.html 
muchas gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`author`: esto especifica el autor de la pagina web. Quien la desarrollo o tambien el autor del articulo. A diferencia de lo que muchos piensan, esto no tiene ningun efecto sobre los motores de busquedas de internet.

`keywords`: Esto son palabras clave que describen tu sitio de internet. A diferencia de `author`, esta sí tiene influencia en las busquedas de los motores de busquedas. Por ejemplo un sitio de internet que trate de programación puede tener en keywords:

```
<meta name="keyword" content="c# c sharp programacion patrones de diseños" />
```

`description`: Esto es la breve descripción que aparece en los resultados de las búsquedas de internet. Mientras mas directa y clara sea la descripcion, mejor sera para los usuarios cuando aparezcan en los resultados:

```
<meta name="description" description="Vea una introduccion a la programacion y le garantizamos que estaras trabajando en 5 meses!" />
```

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias por tu colaboracion.... ahora veras tengo un proyecto de varias paginas html entonces mi pregunta es si estas meta tags las debo poner en todas mis paginas o solamente en el index ???

Comment: El index seria lo mas apropiado. Ahora bien, si estas haciendo un blog lo mejor seria agregarlos en cada post.

Comment: No amigo no es un blog, es mi pagina web, es de un proyecto de mi universidad, etnonces me gustaria saber si estas meta solo deberian ir en mi index o si deberian estar en todas mis paginas html

Comment: En el index bastaria.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. :)